# Filter table column where field is a json object in angular

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-filter

I created a table in HTML and one of its columns is a json.

I want to filter that column by the username field json, like this:

```
<tr
ng-repeat="row in tagUserstory.tasks | 
orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | 
filter: (comboOptionsSelected.num == 3 ? {assignedto.username: searchTaskAssignedto} : searchTask)">
```

`assignedto.username`
where assignedto is a json with username field, but doing this is not possible because throw me error: `expected :`

I also had to create a different filter for this field, because if the filter is undefined for other columns does not work.

I also tried with a function like this:

```
$scope.FilterFunction = function (item) {
        if(item.assignedto == undefined || item.assignedto == ''){
          return false;
        }
        else if(item.assignedto.username == undefined || item.assignedto.username == ''){
          return false;
        }
        else if(item.assignedto.indexOf($scope.searchTaskAssignedto) >= 0){
          return true;
        }
        else{
          return false;
        }


      };
```

In HTML two ways:

```
<tr
 ng-repeat="row in tagUserstory.tasks | 
orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | 
filter: (comboOptionsSelected.num == 3 ? FilterFunction : searchTask)">
```

```
    <tr
     data-ng-repeat="row in tagUserstory.tasks | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | 
     filter:searchTask"
     ng-hide="comboOptionsSelected.num == 3 && !FilterFunction">
```

But the filter shows me all the results that exists.

The same happens if I make a filter in this way:

```
angular.module('myAppAngularMinApp')

  .filter('prueba', function () {
    return function (item, searchTaskAssignedto) {
      if(item.assignedto == undefined || item.assignedto == ''){
        return false;
      }
      else if(item.assignedto.username == undefined || item.assignedto.username == ''){
        return false;
      }
      else if(item.assignedto.indexOf(searchTaskAssignedto) >= 0){
        return true;
      }
      else{
        return false;
      }

    };
  })
```

In HTML:

```
<input ng-show="comboOptionsSelectedTask.num == 3" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchTaskAssignedto"/>

<tr
 ng-repeat="row in tagUserstory.tasks | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter: (comboOptionsSelected.num == 3 ? {prueba : searchTaskAssignedto} : searchTask)">
```

Any idea?

Thank you very much.

Comment: create a custom filter. Easy to search how to do it.

Comment: Yes...can pass parameters to custom filter

Comment: I tried with function :: <p>filter: (comboOptionsSelected.num == 3 ? FilterFunction : searchTask) <p>I leave the function in the question.

Comment: A custom filter is either an `angular.module('myApp').filter()` or a controller function or a function callback to `$filter`. Suggest you read up on `filter` in docs and can do google search for `angular custom filter`

Comment: I know but I found a [link](http://techfunda.com/howto/479/custom-filter-function) that explains that is possible doing this way. I will try with .filter or $filter

Comment: Well I tried with .filter and it doesn't work, I don't know if I am doing something wrong. I put the method in the question.